# How to pass variables from a library to a controller in Appcelerator/Titanium?

Tags: controller, geolocation, appcelerator, lib

I am trying to put the geolocation functionality (getting latitude and longitude) into a library and return latitude and longitude because coordinates are called throughout the app. I can call the geo library from controller.js, the lat and long are shown up in the console, but **how can I use the coordinates** in the calling function from controller.js?

in app/lib/geo.js

```
exports.getLongLat = function checkLocation(){
if (Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled) {
    Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
        if (e.error) {
            Ti.API.error('Error: ' + e.error);
            } else {
                Ti.API.info(e.coords);
                var latitude = e.coords.latitude;
                var longitude = e.coords.longitude;
                console.log("lat: " + latitude + " long: " + longitude);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('location not enabled');
}
```

};

controller.js

```
geolocation.getLongLat(); //this calls the library, but I don't know how I can get the coordinates "back" into the controller.js file for using it in the var args below.

var args ="?display_id=check_if_in_dp_mobile&args[0]=" + lat + "," + lon;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a reusable library for this is a great idea, and you are on the right path. The challenge with [`getCurrentPosition`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-method-getCurrentPosition) is that it is asynchronous, so we have to get the data from it a little differently.

Note in geo.js, the line `Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {...`, there is a function being passed to `getCurrentPosition`.  This is a *callback* function that is executed one the phone has received the location data. This is because `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, meaning that the code in that callback function won't execute until a later point in time. I have some notes on async callbacks [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-method-getCurrentPosition).

With your getLongLat function, the main thing we need to do is pass a callback to it that can in turn be passed to getCurrentPosition.  Something like this:

```
exports.getLongLat = function checkLocation(callback){
    if (Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled) {
        //we are passing the callback argument that was sent from getLongLat
        Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
    } else {
        console.log('location not enabled');
    }
};
```

Then when you execute the function, you will pass the callback to it:

```
//we moved our callback function here to the controller where we call getLongLat
geolocation.getLongLat(function (e) {
    if (e.error) {
        Ti.API.error('Error: ' + e.error);
    } else {
        Ti.API.info(e.coords);
        var latitude = e.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = e.coords.longitude;
        console.log("lat: " + latitude + " long: " + longitude);
    }
});
```

In this case, we're basically moving the contents of that function originally being passed to `getCurrentPosition` out to where you are calling `getLongLat` in your controller.  Now you will be able to do something with the coords data when the callback executes.

Another place where callbacks occur in Titanium apps is with making network requests with `Ti.Network.HttpClient`. [Here](http://adampaxton.com/creating-an-alloy-library-for-appcelerator-titanium-xhr-js/) is a similar example of what you are trying to do by building a library for your geolocation queries only with making HTTPClient requests.

Comment: Many thanks Adam for the clear explanation. Especially the part "basically moving the contents of that...". that was the last missing part that i didnt get.